# MYSQL - Find rows, where part of search string matches part of value in column

Tags: mysql

I wasn't able to find this anywhere, here's my problem:

I have a string like '1 2 3 4 5' and then I have a mysql table that has a column, let's call it numbers, that look like this:

```
numbers

1 2 6 8 9 14   
3              
1 5 3 6 9      
7 8 9 23 44    
10
```

I am trying to find the easiest way (hopefully in a single query) to find the rows, where any of the numbers in my search string (1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) is contained in the numbers column. In the give example I am looking for rows with 1,2 and 3 (since they share numbers with my search string).

I am trying to do this with a single query and no loops.

Thanks!

Comment: Normalize your schema, so you don't have lists of values in a single column.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar, your schema looks like an antipattern. There is no advantage in holding strings and to do string searches when you may have another table with an integer indexable column for the numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately I am faced with a situation where I have to work with what I have. I know this is not a good db design and I agree that ultimately a normal form is the best solution. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to get rid of the column containing a list of values, and use a schema where each value is in its own row. Then you can use `WHERE number IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and join this with the table containing the rest of the data.

But if you can't change the schema, you can use a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE numbers REGEXP '[[:<:]](1|2|3|4|5)[[:<:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:<:]]` match the beginning and end of words.

Note that this type of search will be very slow if the table is large, because it's not feasible to index it.

Comment: This works, but I get 'regular expression is too large' error when the search string is large. Definitely looks like a great solution, but the design of that database seems to make it hard. Still I think I have to redo the database to solve the issue permanently... If this turns out to be my only permanent solution, this answer will be the accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: If the search string is very large, you can split it into smaller groups, and combine them with `OR`. `WHERE numbers REGEXP '[[:<:]](1|2|3|4|5)[[:<:]]' OR numbers REGEXP '[[:<:]](6|7|8|9|10)[[:<:]]'`

Comment: Yes, that worked! Still a normal form is the long terms solution here, but at least I can proceed with that project for now. I have accepted your answer @Barmar. Thank you! Just one clarification, I had to remove the [[:<:]] at the beginning and end, I just used 1|2|3|4|5 etc...

Comment: @Nireti If you do that, searching for `1` will match things like `12`, `31`, `415`, etc. You need the word boundaries to make it match whole words.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is a start point (split string function) : http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/ := SplitString(string,delimiter,position)
2. Create a function so it converts a string to an array := stringSplitted(string,delimiter)
3. Create a function so it compares two arrays :=arrayIntersect(array1, array2)

   ```
   SELECT numbers    
   FROM table    
   WHERE arrayIntersect(@argument, numbers)
   ```

Two function definitions with loops and one single query without any loop

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (numbers LIKE '%1%' OR numbers LIKE '%2%')
```

or you can also use REGEX something like [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/484/use-regular-expressions-in-mysql-select-statements/)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id REGEXP '5587$'
```

Comment: `LIKE '%2%'` will match `23`.

Comment: Also sometimes I end up with a lot of numbers that need to be checked and doing too many ORs is very time consuming. Thanks though.